# What does the Aperture→Lightroom plugin get me that directly importing image files doesn't?

Tags: lightroom, apple-aperture, import

[This thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52437/leaving-apple-aperture-for-adobe-lightroom-is-there-any-way-to-avoid-losing-my) makes it clear that Adobe's plugin for migrating from Aperture to Lightroom does ***not*** support adjustments.

If it doesn't support adjustments, then **what do I get out of using the plugin that I wouldn't also get by directly importing Aperture's Masters folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Adobe's FAQ on the importer](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/aperture-import-plug-in-lightroom-faq.html). It doesn't include adjustments, but *does* include other metadata:

- Flags
- Star Ratings
- Keywords
- GPS Data
- Hidden files
- Face naming tags are mapped to keywords
- some other stuff.

So... not *much* more than just importing the files directly, but if you've used the rating and categorization features heavily, this will preserve that.